# Beginner game-development in C++ and lua

Tags: c++, lua

I am a total Beginner in C++ and programming generaly.

I have watched a couple of hours tutorals of C++ and read alot about it (Could you recommend some tutorials?), but what I´ve come across and couldn´t understand was Librarys.

I want to develop games in C++ (I think, it seems most interesting atm).
I can understand that I need a library for game programming in C++, but I don't know much about what a library is specifically, and where to find these librarys.

Also, I´ve read that Lua should be good to script the games with. I would like to know if this is true? 
If its true, I would like to know where to find tutorials for Lua?
If not true, what is good then?

Thank you for your time.
This is my first question here.
I apologise if it wasn´t a proper question for this website, or if the english was bad. 
I still hope you can give me some kind of answer and/or response.

Comment: Why did you choose C++ for your first language?

Comment: The Ultimate Indie Game Developer Resource List, http://www.mangatutorials.com/forum/showthread.php?742-The-Ultimate-Indie-Game-Developer-Resource-List :p

Comment: For what it's worth, you may also want to use http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

It's a sister site to StackOverflow. Not that this isn't a valid post in StackOverflow, but you might find more help with LUA Game Development on that board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good library to get started with game programming is SDL.  http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials has some great tutorials to help you get started (the most comprehensive and easy to understand that I've found), but you need to understand program structure and such to get some practical use out of the tutorials.

OpenGL is pretty standard for 3D game programming, but it's more advanced than SDL.  I'd recommend making sure you understand at least basic C++ before you move on to game programming... http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial would be a good place to start.

Comment: Im not planing to rush into it, so i´ll go through the tutorials so i know what C++ actualy is, befor starting to even program a smaller game, so thank for the links for tutorials, and thanks for the response. will keep in mind to get a better understanding of C++ befor going into something to advanced for me still.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try out [Löve2d](http://love2d.org/), a framework across Windows, Linux, and MacOS X for writing games in Lua. It bundles various game libraries for sound, graphics, physics etc so that you don't need to deal with that directly, and it lets you focus on the writing of games.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can get very good and complete video tutorial of cs [Indian institute of technology](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses.php?disciplineId=106)

Comment: There is no videos for game!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will come along and post an essay answering your questions in more detail, but here are the short answers.

A library is nothing more than a reusable collection of code. People write code and package it up for other people to use in their own projects. Libraries you would need for games include libraries that handle graphics, audio, networking, font/image loaders, etc.

Lua is great to script games with. It integrates very nicely with C/C++. Visit Lua's home site for tutorials.

Comment: Thank you alot, it might be short, but it game me some thing to work with, and it did give me a better understanding of what a library is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ for libraries here is the STL http://cplusplus.com/reference/.

Here is a reference on Lua, http://lua.gts-stolberg.de/en/index.php?uml=1.

Comment: Thank you very much! i chose C++ because, i didnt really know where to start, i´ve done little with javascript, but only because thats what er learn at school(it´s just a low standard programming class, and the teacher chose to teach us javascript). do you have a sugestion for a better language to start with ?

Answer (score 0):

> can understand that much that I need a library for game programmig in C++, but I dont know much about, what A library is specificly, and where to find these librarys.

@TheBuzzSaw already answers what a library is, so I'll answer where to find. But wait, before WHERE, you have to know WHAT library to use. There are a lot of game libraries out there, both low level (loosely coupled between components) and high level (tightly coupled). The low level ones have separate functionality for graphics, sound, AI, etc. processing and usually each functionality can be used for things other than games. While the high level ones "glue" them together to form something that's ready to use as a whole (for instance, it provides scene class with events, music, etc. you just have to set some values to use). Due to the many number of then, I can't really say where to find before you know which one to use. One quite complete one is [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), it's a low level one. [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) is another one.

> Also, I´ve read that Lua should be good to script the games with. I would like to know if this is true? If its true, I would like to know where to find tutorials for Lua? If not true, what is good then?

Lua is good, and it's used a lot in games. Ruby is good, some games use it. Python is good as well. Basically, most scripting languages are good for game scripting. You just have to consider what language features your game required, how fast you want it to be usually contradict with its syntax flexibility, etc.

Comment: Okay, im still a noob, so i´ll have get more into, but i do see what you mean. Thank you! it is helpful.